# How do I call an Oracle SQL procedure from the command line?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, command-line

How do I call an Oracle stored procedure with parameters?

It has one input and one output parameter, and looks like `doSomething(IN x,OUT y);`.

How do I call it from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming SQL*Plus:

```
var v_result number
exec doSomething(42, :v_result);
print v_result
```

You can put that into a SQL script and pass that on the commandline to SQL*Plus.

Comment: /***********/

I'm getting this 

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

PLS-00201: identifier 'doSomething' must be declared

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored



       V_1
----------



       V_2
----------

Comment: @Anandhakrishnan -- then start by entering `DESCRIBE doSomething` to ensure that the procedure exists, is accessible, and has the signature that you expect

Comment: Perhaps the type of the output variable is incorrect -- you did not tell us what the parameter types were.

Comment: doSomething(x IN NUMBER,y OUT VARCHAR2(100)); is the signature.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
BEGIN
var v_outparam1 number;
var v_outparam2 number;
exec myProc(v_outparam1,v_outparam1);
END;
/
```

Comment: You wouldn't enclose these lines in a `BEGIN/END` block -- they are SQLPlus commands, not PL/SQL statements.